# couchbase.exceptions._TimeoutError_0x17

Tags: python, couchbase

I have a single couchbase and a cluster in the same subnet on EC2.

On OSX 10.12.6 using

`python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 12:04:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin`

Brewed: `libcouchbase-2.8.6.sierra.bottle.tar.gz`
Successfully pip'd installed `couchbase-2.3.4`

Connecting to the single presents no probrlams, but when I connect to the cluster I get

`couchbase.exceptions._TimeoutError_0x17 (generated, catch TimeoutError): <Key='xxx', RC=0x17[Client-Side timeout exceeded for operation. Inspect network conditions or increase the timeout], Operational Error, Results=1, C Source=(src/multiresult.c,316)>`

Yet on `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1052-aws x86_64)` using

`Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 13 2017, 12:02:49) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux`

With `couchbase==2.3.4` I have no problems - all be it from the same subnet.

I use:

```
cluster = Cluster(settings.COUCHBASE_URL)
authenticator = PasswordAuthenticator('admin', settings.COUCHBASE_PASSWORD)
cluster.authenticate(authenticator)
cb = cluster.open_bucket(bucket)
```

where

COUCHBASE_URL=couchbase://xx.xx.xx.xx,xx.xx.xx.xx,xx.xx.xx.xx when I get the error.

and

COUCHBASE_URL=couchbase://xx.xx.xx.xx when I don't.

Any ideas ? Many thanks.

Comment: On Linux, did you try to update form `Python 3.6.3` to `python 3.6.4` then see what will happen? Your version on OS X is `python 3.6.4` which works fine. Not sure, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but this sound similar to some networking issues I've seen when using a single node in docker vs multiple nodes in docker. I suggest trying sdk-doctor to see what the output is: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/sdk-doctor/releases